# Polynomial Ring on Sage

Tags: sagemath

Somebody can explain me what does this function do?

```
class fastfrac:

  def __init__(self,top,bot=1):

    if parent(top) == ZZ or parent(top) == R:
      self.top = R(top)
      self.bot = R(bot)
    elif top.__class__ == fastfrac:
      self.top = top.top
      self.bot = top.bot * bot
    else:
      self.top = R(numerator(top))
      self.bot = R(denominator(top)) * bot
```

For example, parent() function I don't know what does it do. I search information but I didn't find nothing.

Thank you so much

Comment: Well it looks like this function intializes an object of fastfrac class. What it does is that for efficiency it considers some special cases of the ring you work over. Why does it matter?

Comment: Yes, but what does the __init__ function do? Because I know that R is a ring, but I don't know what is R(top) or R(bot), and I don't know why the function compare with ZZ and R

Comment: Note: also asked as [Ask Sage question 43714](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/43714) and on [this blog](http://mathematics.filegala.com/2018/09/19/polynomial-ring-on-sage/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sage, every mathematical object has a parent structure.

For example, an integer's parent would be the ring of integers,
a matrix's parents would be a matrix space, a polynomial's parent
would be the corresponding polynomial ring, etc.

To know what the object's parent is, one can use the function
`parent` or the method `parent` of this object.

For example, having defined:

```
sage: N.<u> = NumberField(x^2 - x - 1)
sage: P.<t> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: R.<y, z> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
```

and

```
sage: a = 3
sage: b = 6/2
sage: c = x + 3 - x
sage: d = t + 3 - t
sage: e = y + 3 - y
sage: f = mod(3, 8)
```

you could see that they all display as 3 but all have
different parents.